# AngularJs routing is failing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="hotelApp">

  <head>
    <title>SRK Hotel</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"> -->

    <!-- Angular dependencies -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/angular-material/angular-material.css">
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>


    <script src="scripts/start.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/home-page-ctrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/states/misc-states.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- <div data-ng-include="'views/welcome-page.html'"></div> -->
    <div ui-view="welcome"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

My app.js

```
(function() {

    angular.module('hotelApp.controller', []);
    angular.module('hotelApp.states', ['ui.router']);

    angular.module('hotelApp', ['ui.router']);



})();
```

My states.js - that is there for declaration of states

```
angular.module('hotelApp.states')
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 
    'use strict';


    $stateProvider
        .state('hotelApp.homePage', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'welcome': {
                    templateUrl: 'views/welcome-page.html',
                    conntroller: 'homePageCtrl'
                }
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', function($state){
    console.log('$state ' , $state);
        $state.go('hotelApp.homePage');
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function(){
        console.log('hi');
    });


    });
```

my nodejs file

```
var express = require('express');

var cfenv = require('cfenv');


var app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/views'));

app.use('/lib', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));


app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html');
});


var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();

app.listen(appEnv.port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
  console.log("server starting on " + appEnv.url);
});
```

I am trying to use routing in this implementation but it is failing.
I have added this code but when i run my code.. nothing happens .. I just get a blank  page. What is wrong with this implementation.? I get no error, no logs.

Comment: which route you are accessing in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main module is defined as

```
angular.module('hotelApp', ['ui.router']);
```

So it depends exclusively on ui-router.

Your states are defined in a separate module, 'hotelApp.states', which is thus not part of your application.

Another problem is that the two JS files you've posted are app.js and states.js, and there is no `<script>` element in your html page for those two files. So the're not even loaded by the browser.

Comment: This fixes the above issue. But now the HTML is not loading in ui-view.
I have added
 `angular.module('hotelApp', ['ui.router', 'hotelApp.states','hotelApp.controller'])
 .run(function($state){
  $state.go('hotelApp.homePage');
 });`
in start.js

Comment: First of all, don't name your state 'hotelApp.homePage'. This defines a homePage state that is a child of a hotelApp state that doesn't exist.

Comment: I haven't added those scripts here.. they are there :P

Comment: _First of all, don't name your state 'hotelApp.homePage'. This defines a homePage state that is a child of a hotelApp state that doesn't exist_
***yup corrected it already .. (it threw error ):)***